# CSS Styling for div layout

Tags: html, css

Please see my HTML structure below - I am trying to have the `.prod` divs to be to the right of the logo, and the logo to be the full height of the `.row` div

I know this can be done using `tables` and `floats` but I want to try and avoid using those.

Here's my structure:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row .image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 24%;
}

.row .prod {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
}

.prod > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: Calc(50% - 4px);
}

div {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img alt="Full Height Logo" src="" />
  </div>

  <div class="prod">
    <div class="prod_image">
      <img alt="Product Image" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="prod_info">
      Prod Info
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prod">
    <div class="prod_image">
      <img alt="Product Image" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="prod_info">
      Prod Info
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle with (working) images? Because your problem is not really clear to me...

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet" to see the result.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, because now it all makes sense.

Comment: How is a fiddle and actual images going to make any difference? it will look the same. It's pretty simple what I want - the `.prod` divs to be to the right of the logo, and the logo to be the full height of the `.row` div

Comment: I personally life floats. But you could always try z-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the additional info inside another div and give it the remaining width.

I have given it `74%` because of the extra space from inline-block elements. Adjust it to your requirement. I would prefer `flexbox` if you are implementing it for modern browsers.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.row .image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 24%;
  vertical-align: top; /* Default to baseline, align to the top */
}
.row .product_info { 
  width: 74%; /* Remaining width */
}
.row .product_info .prod {
  /* width: 75% */ Remove
  height: auto;
}
.prod > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: Calc(50% - 4px);
}
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img alt="Full Height Logo" src="" />
  </div>
  <div class="product_info">
    <div class="prod">
      <div class="prod_image">
        <img alt="Product Image" src="" />
      </div>
      <div class="prod_info">
        Prod Info
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="prod">
      <div class="prod_image">
        <img alt="Product Image" src="" />
      </div>
      <div class="prod_info">
        Prod Info
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`flexbox` can do that.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.image,
.prod {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  height: 75px;
}
.image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img alt="Full Height Logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-50-50-1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="prod">
    <div class="prod_image">
      <img alt="Product Image" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="prod_info">
      Prod Info
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prod">
    <div class="prod_image">
      <img alt="Product Image" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="prod_info">
      Prod Info
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of `flexbox` vs an additional wrapper?

Comment: Well, I don't need another wrapper to start with...so that's one. I don't need to set specific widths or use `calc` for another. Browser support is an issue for `flexbox` quite often but it's not bad. I'm just giving options...not saying one is better than the other. Frankly, you could just as easily use a table since this does seem to be tabular data.

Comment: I always have trouble picking out which methods to use. Would you be able to post also how you would do it without another wrapper? because that is really what I was hoping for

Comment: Oooh, I see now. Got it. First time coming across `flexbox` I've heard of it, but never really used it. I'll have to do some more research on it, but for now just have to stick with what I know.

Comment: If you want to research`flexbox` (and you should..it's gonna take over) then the link in the answer below (on CSS-Tricks.com) should be your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox?

I'm still pretty new to flexbox myself, but you could use the `align-items: stretch` property on your container to cause your items to stretch, but give the `.prod` div's a max-height so that they only stretch so much. You can also set various widths properties using the `flex` property on your flex items so that you get the width your after.

For more information: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Links to a tool or library should include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and ideally [**also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, that would be the paragraph above the link.

Comment: But other than a vague recommendation and a link it's not really a full answer IMO...others might differ.

Comment: My apologies, the question didn't have a extremely specific desired result other than the one div being full height and the other divs being to the right, which I addressed in my paragraph.